# Components cant communicate with each other

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I'm using Angular 6 and I'm trying to make communicate 2 components. The second component have to start a specific animation based on the URL of the first component. I tried to use "previous URL" solutions but they didn't always work, so I thought to make communicate the 2 components. In the first one, there is one button that is the only way to reach the second component. So when it's pressed it calls a function that sends a message to the second component declaring the current URL. I looked for a suitable solution and I implemented that, with no success. The second component can't read the message at all and I don't know why since I use this system to make communicate another 2 components in my project. 
This is the code of the first component:

**HTML**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="api.availableAPI==true">
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <button type="button" (click)="send('test_message');" class="card-gray-button" [routerLink]=api.linkPlayground>TRY NOW</button>
      </ng-container>
```

**Typescript**

```
import { ResetService } from './../../../services/reset.service';
import { PreviousUrlService } from './../../../services/previous-url.service';
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ApiCard } from "../../model/ApiCard";

@Component({
  selector: "api-card",
  templateUrl: "./api-card.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./api-card.component.scss"]
})
export class ApiCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() api: ApiCard;
  constructor(private resetService: ResetService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

// --> RIGHT HERE
  send(message: string): void {
    this.resetService.sendMessage(message);
    console.log('function called');
  }
}
```

This is the second component:

**Typescript**

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { CATEGORIES } from './mock-category';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd, Params, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { until } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { ResetService } from './../services/reset.service';
import elementIsSelected = until.elementIsSelected;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-documentation',
  templateUrl: './api-documentation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./api-documentation.component.scss']
})
export class ApiDocumentationComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  @Input() inputField: string;

  myInnerHeight = 500;
  categories = CATEGORIES;
  private fragment: string;
  private url: string;
  baseUrl = 'https://external-api.intesasanpaolo.com/playground/';
  apiTitle: string;
  apiDescription: string;
  landingBackgroundImage: string;
  message: any;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
    private resetService: ResetService) {
    this.subscription = this.resetService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message; });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
      this.fragment = fragment;
      this.ngAfterViewInit();
    });
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.apiTitle = data.title;
      this.apiDescription = data.description;
      this.landingBackgroundImage = data.heroImage;
    });
    this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const patt = new RegExp('//api_documentation*/');
        if (patt.test(val.url)) {
          this.router.navigate(['/api_documentation']);
        } else { this.router.navigate([val.url]); }
      }
    });
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.previousUrl = event.url;
      }
    });
    this.receive();
  }

  viewCategory(nameCategory: String) {
    for (let i in this.categories) {
      if (this.categories[i].name === nameCategory) {
        if (this.categories[i].view) {
          this.categories[i].view = false;
        } else { this.categories[i].view = true; }
      }
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    autoscroll();
  }

  autoscroll(): void {
    if (this.previousUrl === '/account-information') {
      this.scrollToCategory('Account_Balance');
    }
    if (this.previousUrl === '/payments') {
      this.scrollToCategory('sepa_instant_payment');
    }
    if (this.previousUrl === '/tools') {
      this.scrollToCategory('iban_existance_verification');
    }
  }


// --> RIGHT HERE
  receive(): void {
    if (this.message != null) {
      console.log('success: ' + this.message.text);
    } else {
      console.log('failure');
    }
  }

  scrollToCategory(s: String) {
    let htmlElement: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(
      '#' + s
    ) as HTMLElement;
    var posElemento: number = htmlElement.offsetTop;
    posElemento -= 32;

    try {
      document.querySelector('#container-right').scrollTo({ left: 0, top: posElemento - 10, behavior: 'smooth' });
    } catch (e) {
      document.querySelector('#container-right').scrollTop = posElemento;
    }
    // (document.querySelector('#prova')).querySelector('#' + this.fragment).scrollIntoView();
  }

}
```

And this is the service I use:

**Typescript**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResetService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  sendMessage(message: string) {
      this.subject.next({ text: message });
  }

  clearMessage() {
      this.subject.next();
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
      return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

If you have any advice, I'll gladly hear from you. Thanks!

Comment: I think using event emitter might be more simple

Comment: try calling receive() in the subscription of getMessage().